# UI5 - Count distinct values in a sap.m.table

Tags: sapui5, xmltable

I have a UI5 Table created with SAP Web IDE.

I want the table to have 2 columns.
The first one should show my distinct values extracted from an ODATA Service and the second one should display the count of my values.

For example:

Value  / Count

100 /  1

200 / 3

010 / 25

So far I have created the table with my values from SAP.
But they are not unique yet - the first column is showing every value.

Value
100

200

200

200

and so on.

How can i group all my values and display the respective count of values?

Here's my code:

Page.view.xml

```
                    <Table id="Table" items="{/ODATASet}">
                        <headerToolbar>
                            <Toolbar>
                                <Title level="H2" text="Data"></Title>
                                <ToolbarSpacer></ToolbarSpacer>
                                <Button icon="sap-icon://refresh" tooltip="Reinitialize Model" press="onModelRefresh"/>
                            </Toolbar>
                        </headerToolbar>
                        <columns>
                            <Column>
                                <Label text="Values"></Label>
                            </Column>
                            <Column>
                                <Label text="Count"></Label>
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <ColumnListItem>
                                <cells>
                                    <Text text="{INTST}"></Text>
                                </cells>
                            </ColumnListItem>
                        </items>
                    </Table>
```

Page.controller.js:

```
        //Accessing the table from the fragment by it's Id  
        var oTable = this.byId("Table");

        //column list item creation
        var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{INTST}"
            })]
        });
        var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ODATAService";
        //Adding service to the odata model
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, false);
        //Setting model to the table
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindAggregation("items", {
            path: "/ODATASet",
            template: oTemplate
        });
    },
```

Comment: have you tried to get json data from odata service, loop at it and find counts then generate a new json model and bind it to the view instead of odata model?

Comment: so no odata model, instead i have to create a json model? how can i loop over the results? in vue js i did it via lodash - is that possible?

Comment: I have no idea about your second question. Just an idea, you should loop over your data that you get from odata service, right? Because you want to make some calculation. So after that you should save this new data in somewhere else and that's a json model. I can't see any other solution for this kind of requirement. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it via lodash:

```
        $
            .ajax({
                url: '/sap/opu/odata/sap/ODATAService',
                jsonpCallback: 'getJSON',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                    oModel.setData(data);
                    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
                    //Create a model and bind the table rows to this model
                    //Get the forecastday array table from txt_forecast object
                    var aData = oModel.getProperty("/d/results");
                    var aData2 = _.countBy(_.map(aData, function(d) {
                        return d.DATE;
                    }));
                    var aData3 = Object.keys(aData2).sort().map(key => ({
                        key,
                        value: aData2[key]
                    }));
                    oModel.setData({
                        modelData: aData3
                    });
                    oTable2.setModel(oModel);
                }
            });
```